# .htaccess rule to friendly URL not working

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to create a rule for friendly URLs. I just looked for other examples in Stack Overflow, but can't find a solution. I'm pretty sure the code is correct, but it is not working.

For example: `/index.php?p=about` must become `/about`

This rule is working:

```
RewriteRule ^about/?$ index.php?p=about
```

But this one (to work with all pages) is not:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /index.php?p=$1 [L]
```

I would like to use the second rule, to work with all pages, not only with the about page. May anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your 2nd rule to this:

```
# If the request is not for a valid directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# If the request is not for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?p=$1 [L,QSA]
```

`QSA` (Query String Append) flag preserves existing query parameters while adding a new one.

Comment: Oh, it worked like a charm! Thank you so much. BTW, I didn't know the QSA flag.